# Fastest way to query a specific record from API

Tags: mongoose, baucis

I'm working with a REST API built with Mongoose and Baucis. It's fantastic, and was very easy to put together.

I'm wondering, when querying for a single record, the response from the server typically faster when specifying the the record ID as part of the path, or part of the condition statement? Or does it matter?

For example:

`http://www.example.com/path/to/endpoint/record_id/`

OR

`http://www.example.com/path/to/endpoint/?conditions={"_id": "record_id"}`

Thanks!

Comment: Performance always depends on the environment. No answer you get here will compare to actual test data.

Answer (score 1):

Both map to the same Mongo query and almost exactly the same code paths in Baucis and Mongoose.  So, the performance difference would be practically indistinguishable.